# JavaScript dynamically attaching to a Search field

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway in JavaScript to scan the HTML and obtain the id of an input field for example a search bar would have:

```
<input id="searchBar">
```

and then read the text directly from there? Especially if this is to run on multiple different html documents so the actual id cannot be hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` to return an array of all `input` elements on a page, then loop through the array and grab the ID of the elements by accessing the `.id` property. While you're at it, I think you can use the `.value` property to get the content of the input.

So something like

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    console.log(inputs[i].id);
    console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
```

If you particularly wanted to use the ID, then you could also go with `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: This looks great! So if needed you wouldn't actually need to specify which input id you're after you could simply read the contents of every input field on a page?

Comment: Yep, that's right. You can grab elements by their Id, name, class name or type (i.e. input, select) using vanilla JavaScript, if you want to use JQuery, you get the ability to select by pretty much anything that makes up an HTML element, plus an arguably friendlier way to find elements